# Is some syntax exists for type annotation of decomposed to declared in advance variables array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

In my standard, all types annotations **where possible** are required, so TypeScrit-ESLint tells me to annotate the `[ responseData, cognitoUser ]`. However, the syntax `[ responseData1: ResponseData1, responseData2: ResponseData2]` is invalid (`TS1005: ';' expected`). If there is no such syntax, it's the issue in TypeScript/ESLint repository.

```js
let responseData1: ResponseData1;
let responseData2: ResponseData2;

try {
  [ responseData1, responseData2] = await Promise.all([ /* ... */ ])
} catch {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: what rule is firing? You've provided very little information here.

Answer (score 1):

From TS 4 you can add labels for array types.

```
type ResponseData = [responseData1: ResponseData1, responseData2: ResponseData2];
```

And you can use it for your Promise.all:

```
try {
  const [responseData1, responseData2]: ResponseData = await Promise.all([ /* ... */ ])
} catch {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but I can't apply your solution to my case because in your solution `responseData1` and `responseData2` has been declared in `try` block so they can not be used outside of `try` bock. Is some valid syntax for my case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a overall pattern you need to follow for destructuring from Promise.all and catch the errors:

```
function getFoo(): Promise<number> {
  return Promise.resolve(2);
}

function getBar(): Promise<number> {
  return Promise.resolve(3);
}

async function getResults(): Promise<{ foo: number; bar: number }> {
  try {
    const [foo, bar] = await Promise.all([getFoo(), getBar()]);
    return { foo, bar };
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error("something went wrong.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, but I can't apply your solution to my case because in your solution responseData1 and responseData2 has been declared in try block so they can not be used outside of try bock. Is some valid syntax for my case?

Comment: destructuring happens on the return of Promise.all and that is the only place you can declare the variables. There is no case for those variables being declared earlier.

Comment: Got it. It means I need to open the issue in TypeScript/ESLint repository.

Comment: If I understand correctly your main concern is being able to annotate the destructured variables. But you don't need to worry about this as their type is perfectly derived from the return of Promise.all by TypeScript. So in my example the language is no doubt that foo and bar are numbers.

Comment: So in your example, If your Promise.all is returning the correct things, then TS already knows that responseData1 is ResponseData1 and responseData2 is ResponseData2, you don't need to declare variables to help the language make that inference.

Comment: Just const [ responseData1, responseData2] = await Promise.all(... is sufficient